# C++ Type Traits Overview

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, compile-time, type-traits

Has anybody put together a list of all the type traits available in standard `<type_traits>` (GCC-4.6.1) and Boost's own `<boost/type_traits.hpp>`?

Comment: Here are your lists: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference.html and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf §20.9.2

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: By referring to the C++0x draft, are you asserting that GCC's implementation of `<type_traits>` is complete as of version 4.6.1?

Comment: @SteveJessop oh, no. I know for a fact it isn't. Somehow I didn't read that part. I think I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full lists of traits are available online:

- The Boost documentation lists the traits in [`<boost/type_traits.hpp>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference.html);
- The C++0x draft lists the traits in [`<type_traits>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).

However, the GCC implementation is not yet complete. GCC 4.6 is missing:

- The `std::underlying_type` trait. This one will be on GCC 4.7.
- The `std::is_trivially_X` series of traits. Instead it has `std::has_trivial_default_constructor` and similar that seem to have the name from an earlier draft. The one about the move constructor is missing.
- The `std::is_nothrow_X` series of traits. These also use an older name like `std::has_nothrow_default_constructor`. The one about the move constructor is missing too.
- The `std::aligned_union` trait. This one can be easily implemented in terms of `std::aligned_storage`, which is currently supported.