# Misunderstanding of range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, enum-class

A compiler error occurs when I try to compile the following code:

```
for(binary_instructions_t &inst: BinaryInstructions){


}
```

`BinaryInstructions` is this enum class:

```
typedef unsigned int binary_instructions_t;

enum class BinaryInstructions : binary_instructions_t
{
    END_OF_LAST_INSTR = 0x0,

    RESET,
    SETSTEP,
    START,
    STOP,

    ADD,
    REMOVE,
};
```

Should I be allowed to "do a" range based for loop using the items inside an enum class? Or have I subtly misunderstood in that range based for loops are for searching the contents of an array and not stuff like enum classes?

I have also tried: Creating an instance and searching within the instance:

```
BinaryInstructions bsInstance;
for(binary_instructions_t &inst : bsInstance){


}
```

But no cigar... Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The range-based for loop needs a collection, like an array or a vector. The enum class isn't a collection.

However, it's C++, so there's a workaround. See: [Allow for Range-Based For with enum classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498300/allow-for-range-based-for-with-enum-classes)

Comment: that sweet! I love that implementation. Much cleaner than the casting to int solution I would have used.

Answer (score 0):

Range-based for-loops are a mechanism for easy iteration over a list of elements. A 'list of elements' can be a plain array or an instance of a class that implements the `begin`and `end` methods returning an iterator type.

Example:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (int cur : arr)
   std::cout << cur << std::endl;
```