# Iteration over enum class in a project

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, code-separation

I am following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498300/allow-for-range-based-for-with-enum-classes) for iterating over an enum.

```
enum class COLOR
{
    Blue,
    Red,
    Green,
    Purple,
    First=Blue,
    Last=Purple
};

COLOR operator++( COLOR& x ) { return x = (COLOR)(((int)(x) + 1)); }

COLOR operator*(COLOR c) {return c;}

COLOR begin(COLOR r) {return COLOR::First;}
// end iterator needs to return one past the end!
COLOR end(COLOR r)   {return COLOR(int(COLOR::Last) + 1);}
```

The problem is that in my project, there are many `cpp` and `hpp` files which are compiled separately. It seems the compiler needs to have direct access to implementation of `operator++`. If I declare in a `hpp` and then implement in `cpp` file, I will face with error:

> compiler warning: inline function ‘Color operator++(Color&)’ used but never defined
>
> linker error: undefined reference to `operator++(instruction_type&)'

If I define it directly in `hpp`, I will face with another error

> multiple definition of ...

for `operator*`, `begin`, and `end` in linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `inline` keyword in front of your 4 functions will allow them to be defined in the header without the multiple definition errors.  For example:

```
inline COLOR operator*(COLOR c) {return c;}
```

Or you can include just the prototype in the .h file and define the functions in 1 .cpp file.