# Unable to iterate over enum

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clr

I'm currently unable to iterate over my Enum values using the following code:

```
enum class Animals { Ducks, Giraffes, Hamster };

Array^ temp = Enum::GetValues(Animals::typeid);
Console::WriteLine("LENGTH = " + temp->Length);
for (int iter = 0; iter < temp->Length; iter++)
{
    Console::WriteLine("ITER = " + iter);
}
```

It results in the following:

```
LENGTH = 0
```

I have followed the following documentation entry:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks for your time

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498300/allow-for-range-based-for-with-enum-classes) how to do new range-style enums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++11 language revision has adopted several keywords that were in use in C++/CLI.  Like `nullptr`, `override`, `final`.  And the `enum class` keyword.  That makes your Animals type an *unmanaged* type in recent VS versions and Enum::GetValues() incapable of discovering enum values since it relies on reflection.

`override` and `final` don't byte since they are contextual keywords.  `nullptr` is troublesome, but it stays the managed flavor and `__nullptr` is the unmanaged flavor.  The workaround for `enum class` is unintuitive, you must declare it with a top-level type visibility specifier (public or private).  Syntax that isn't valid in native C++.  Fix:

```
   public enum class Animals { Ducks, Giraffes, Hamster };
```